# modulo large numbers

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have this RSA-crypto question on my exam, to make a long story short, we do not need to go in to all details about the question, but rather the specifics with which I get stuck.

I have no idea how to solve this specific task:

http://s22.postimg.org/rh0vgoaz5/Sk_rmavbild_2015_10_22_kl_22_39_02.png

Sorry that the picture is not uploaded here directly but I don't have enough reputation here to do so, so please click the link.

They are using mod 779 btw.

Now What I don't get is how they can simplify 574^2 to -41. Because from what I see neither Fermat's little theorem or Eulers theorem can be applied here, are they using some other formula? Cause if not, this seems next to impossible to calculate without a calculator, and calculators are not allowed on the best.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LongMultiplication.html

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LongDivision.html

```
   574
 x 574
------
2870
 4018
+ 2296
------
329476

         422
     -------
779 | 329476
      3116|
      ----v
       1787
       1558
       ----
        2296
        1558
        ----
         738  <- remainder
```

$738 \equiv 738\hspace{-0.04 in}-\hspace{-0.05 in}779 \equiv -\hspace{.02 in}(779\hspace{-0.04 in}-\hspace{-0.05 in}738) \equiv -\hspace{.02 in}42 \;\;\; \pmod{779}$